# Prove that polynomial of degree $4$ with real roots cannot have $\pm 1$ as coefficients (IITJEE)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quadratics

So I was going through  my 11th class package on *Quadratic equations* and I saw a question to prove that a polynomial of $4$th degree with all real roots cannot have $\pm 1$ as all its coefficients.

I tried proving it using calculus, by showing that at least one consecutive maxima  and minima will lie either above or below the x axis, but couldn't solve it using that.

I also tried using Descartes Rule of Signs but couldn't solve it with that too.
Any help?

Comment: Boring / unenlightening approach: There are, essentially, only $16$ such polynomials. One could just go through each of them, with the help of WolframAlpha, and check. Would only take a minute or two.

Comment: I like the approaches taken by OP.  Note that taking a second derivative might close down the number of cases to consider substantially.

Comment: To be precise, there are $32$ such polynomials

Comment: @asdf But $f$ and $-f$ have the same roots, so we may WLOG assume the polynomial is monic. That's what I meant by "essentially". In fact, $f(x)$ and $f(-x)$ are closely related too, so $8$ cases left to check.

Comment: True, I thought you aren't narrowing the cases in any way before bashing it out

Comment: On one hand you say you *can* solve via calculus, on other hand you say *cannot* solve via Descartes. (but then you insert "too" at that point, it's confusing whether you do or don't have already some kind of proof)

Comment: Arthur what you are saying is fine, but really I was looking for some sort of concrete proof. Anybody can log on wolfram and check but I won't learn anything new that way. Also coffee math I don't have any proof

Comment: Hardmath:Also taking a second derivative and using rolles's theorem doesn't help too since the quadratic formed on taking the second derivative can have both real and imaginary roots. The discriminant of the second derivative takes form 36a^2-96bc where a,b,c are +-1.

Comment: @Arthur When I read it I think it said "could solve" using calc. But mayb edit history shows me wrong, anyway I'll likely delete my comment above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be any quartic polynomial with coefficients from $\{ -1, +1 \}$. Replacing $f(x)$ by $-f(x)$ if necessary, we can assume $f(x)$ is monic. i.e.

$$f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d\quad\text{ with }\quad a,b,c,d \in \{ -1, +1 \}$$

If $f(x)$ has $4$ real roots $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\lambda_4$, then by [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas), we have

$$\sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i = -a, \sum_{1\le i < j\le 4} \lambda_i\lambda_j = b
\quad\text{ and }\quad\prod_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i = d$$
Notice
$$\sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i^2 = \left(\sum_{i=1}^4\lambda_i\right)^2 - 2\sum_{1\le i < j \le 4}\lambda_i\lambda_j = a^2 - 2b = 1 -2b$$

Since $\sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i^2 \ge 0$, we need $b = -1$. As a result, $$\sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i^2 = 3$$
By AM $\ge$ GM, this leads to

$$\frac34 = \frac14\sum_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i^2 \ge \left(\prod_{i=1}^4 \lambda_i^2\right)^{1/4} = (d^2)^{1/4} = 1$$
This is impossible and hence $f(x)$ cannot has 4 real roots.

Comment: You are not using at any point that the sum of product of triples is $\pm1$, so the claim can be generalised?

Comment: @asdf yes, the proof doesn't need the value of $c$.

Comment: Nice, $(+1)$ from me

Comment: Achille thanks for answering. However I'm an 11th grader and this looks out of my depth(this is in fact from my textbook). So can you explain to me what you have in a more basic manner? Thanks.Again if this cannot be explained to an 11th grader then I would still consider this question as still unanswered since it was designed to be solved by an 11th grader. Thanks a lot again mate.

Comment: If $f(x) = x^4 + ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d = (x-\lambda_1)(x-\lambda_2)(x-\lambda_3)(x-\lambda_4)$. when you expand the RHS out and compare coefficients, you find $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \lambda_3 + \lambda_4 = -a$ and $\lambda_1\lambda_2 + \lambda_1\lambda_3 + \lambda_1\lambda_4 + \lambda_2\lambda_3 + \lambda_2\lambda_4 + \lambda_3\lambda_4 = b$. You then use this to deduce $\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 + \lambda_3^2 + \lambda_4^2 = 3$ and use AM ge GM to derive a contradiction. This is Vieta's formulas and I though this is taught before calculus?

Comment: @JamesAdams If you are in India, then I can say this is pretty much part of the curriculum (for JEE or your board exams).

Comment: @JamesAdams If you expand $a^2 = (\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\lambda_4)^2$ out completely, you get $$(\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 + \lambda_3^2+\lambda_4^2) + 2(\lambda_1\lambda_2 + \lambda_1\lambda_3 + \lambda_1\lambda_4 + \lambda_2\lambda_3 + \lambda_2\lambda_4 + \lambda_3\lambda_4)\\ = (\lambda_1^2 + \lambda_2^2 + \lambda_3^2+\lambda_4^2) + 2b$$

Comment: @JamesAdams I don't remember how long I take, it is not that long. Since you are in 11 grade, I stop using anything that need calculus and looks for pure algebraic solution. I first look at tools like [Newton inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_inequalities) or [Maclaurin inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maclaurin's_inequality) for polynomials for hints of an elementary solution (these tools are beyond 11 grade) but that didn't work. I switch to use Vieta's formula and attempt to bound the  roots directly. That work and the rest is filling the details.

Answer (score 6):

It can be assumed WLOG that the leading coefficient is $\,+1\,$, so $\,P(x)=x^4\pm x^3\pm x^2\pm x\pm 1\,$.

- Then $\,P''(x)=12x^2 \pm 6x \pm 2\,$, and for the quadratic to have real roots it is necessary that the constant term be negative, so $\,P(x)=x^4\pm x^3 - x^2\pm x\pm 1\,$.
- $P(x)\,$ has all the roots real iff $\,x^4 P\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\,$ has all real roots. By the same argument as above, the constant term of $\,P(x)\,$ must have opposite sign as the coefficient of $\,x^2\,$.

This leaves $4$ cases to check $\,P(x)=x^4\pm x^3 - x^2\pm x+1\,$.

---

[ *EDIT* ]

- $P(x)\,$ has all the roots real iff $\,P\left(-x\right)\,$ has all real roots, so it is enough to consider the case where the coefficient of $\,x^3\,$ is $+1$.

This leaves $2$ cases to check $\,P(x)=x^4+ x^3 - x^2\pm x+1\,$.

Comment: @RossMillikan On the other hand, it is enough to consider one of the cases $\,\pm x^3\,$, as noted in the latest edit.