# If $f(x)$ is a function with all coefficients $1$ or $-1$ and all roots real then degree of $f(x)$ can be

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, functions

If $f(x)$ is a real function with all roots real and $f(x)$ has all its coefficients $1$ or $-1$. (Some can be 1 and others can be -1 but no other value) . Then we have to find the constraint on degree of $f(x)$. 
My attempt : Let $f(x)$ be 
 
$a_{0}x^{n} +a_{1}x^{n-1} + ....+ a_{n-1}x +a_{n}$
 So we have sum of roots(S) = $+1$ or $-1$ , Similarly product of roots taken two at once(P)= $+1$ or $-1$.
 So sum of squares of roots = $S^2 - 2P$ .
This must be greater than 0.Solving this we get sum of squares of roots is equal to $3$. (Excluding the case when degree is$1$).But after this I couldn't arrive at any satisfactory result. 

Note :: We have not been taught calculus yet.

Comment: $x^3 - x^2 -x+1 = (x-1)^2(x+1)$ shows $n=3$ is possible. I think $n\geq 4$ is not possible.

Comment: @Calvin Lin Your answer is correct but how to prove it?

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853502/prove-that-polynomial-of-degree-4-with-real-roots-cannot-have-pm-1-as-coeff?rq=1

Comment: @Macavity That was for 4 degree polynomial , but my question is in general for any polynomial.

Comment: @Abhinav As was pointed out in the comment of the accepted answer to that question, the proof easily generalises to degrees greater than 4.

Comment: @Qiyu WenThanks I got it.